# RESTful form prior to deleting a record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

We have a Rails app where we frequently have interstitial pages before deleting a record. Maybe a simple confirmation that details the consequences of deleting a record, or in other cases we need additional information. For example, when a user is deleted we may need the current user to select where to transfer associated records. It's not clear to me, however, what is the RESTful convention for retrieving the page/form needed to delete a record.

In Rails parlance, we have a `GET` request to `new` to retrieve the form to then `POST` and `create` a new record. There's a `GET` request to `edit` to retrieve the form to then `PATCH` `update` a record, but there isn't a corresponding action to `GET` the form to `DELETE` a record. Is there a RESTful convention for this sort of thing?

In adherence with the 7 RESTful actions given in Rails, we might create a new `UserDeletionsController` with `new` and `create` actions, but that feels pretty clunky, and kind of misaligned in that we're *deleting* a record via a `POST` to `create`. We're considering adding an 8th acceptable action, something like a `GET` request to `/users/5/delete` which retrieves the form. The form would then submit a `DELETE` request to `/users/5`. What other alternatives are there?

Answer (score 0):

I think the main problem that people confuse REST APIs with webapplications. REST is mostly for machine to machine communication in a (semi) standardized way. It is possible to use a REST API from a browser with a javascript based REST client. Without javascript the browser is the worst possible REST client and that's why we had URLs containing methods like `/new` and `/delete`. As of the question the `GET /users/5` should return a hyperlink with an URI template something like `UserDeletionOperation DELETE /users/5?details={additionalInfo}` and your API documentation should contain what you expect for `additionalInfo` in the case of `UserDeletionOperation`. You can make the documentation public with something like `GET /docs/UserDeletionOperation/additionalInfo` Ofc. you can have many different parameters for that operation, so this is just a basic example. Or if there is a standard solution for the operation e.g. schema.org, then better to use that one. For a (semi) general REST client it is even funnier if you use RDF and the hydra vocab to describe your API documentation and resources.