# REST conventions for a friends list

Tags: rest, conventions

I have a database (ORM) with users which look like this:

```
UserEntity (
   id: UUID,
   name: String,
   phoneNumber: String,
   friends: List<UserEntity>
)
```

I also have the following friends endpoints:

```
GET /user/<userId>/friends (returns a list of UUID's for all friends the user has)
POST /user/<userId>/friends?friendId=<friendId> (saves a new friend to the friends list)
DELETE /user/<userId>/friends?friendId=<friendId> (deletes a friend from the friends list)
```

Now I asked myself: is this the correct way of implementing a RESTful friend list and what is a good REST convention to obtain the profile of a friend. Should the friend resource be reached from the following path:

```
GET /user/<userId>/friends/<friendId>
```

Or from this path:

```
GET /user/<friendId>
```

Both of the given endpoints from above give back the same resource (a profile) but which one should I choose? I am diving deeper into REST conventions but I didn't find any clear answer for this. I dont't even know if my current REST design is correct. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: REST doesn't care what spelling conventions you use for your resource identifiers.

Comment: @VoiceOfUnreason It's not about the spelling, it's about the reachability of a sub resource from a main resource in a RESTful way. So should a friend of a user be reached from the user resource itself (e.g. /user/<userId>/friends/<friendId>) or as a user (e.g. /user/<friendId>)? But maybe your are right and REST doesn't tell me anything about this.

Answer (score 0):

What you are talking about I would call nice URL convention. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clean_URL It has nothing to do with REST [https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/fielding_dissertation.pdf](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/fielding_dissertation.pdf) and I have no idea why people think it has. From the REST point of view it would be equally good to do something like `GET|PUT|DELETE /dsgvs23w?x235rwef=1&aegs234523f=2` and decide which URL to follow based on the metadata that describes it. If you violate HATEOAS, then you don't have a REST API.

As of the nice URL convention I would do something like `GET /friendships/?user=1` and `GET|PUT|DELETE /friendships/1+2` and add some extra info about the friendship e.g. `strength=BFF, duration=20y, etc`. But there are infinite good solutions for this and it really depends on your needs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I thought REST tells me something about the location of the resources (e.g. friends). But I don't know what to do with sub resources of a main resource in a common RESTful way (e.g. user->friends). But as you said, it may have nothing to do with REST conventions and it's all about the URL design.

Comment: @MartinNöbel Maybe this helps to make things cleaner regarding to REST: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72046122/607033